# Magento "addAttributeToFilter like" with OR statement not working

Tags: php, magento, filter, sql-like, addattribute

I working on a Magento project, but i seriously stuck.

I want to add 2 *LIKE* checks in my query.

Now my code looks like this:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%'.$_GET["keyword"].'%'),
        array('attribute' => 'att_wine_alias', 'like' => '%'.$_GET["keyword"].'%')
    )
);
```

**att_wine_alias**:
textarea with misspellings or tags

So, if i use this code, Magento didn't search in **name** field. And if i delete the **att_wine_alias** attribute from filter, **name** search works fine.

I want to search in both **fields** with *"like"* using OR statement.

What did I do wrong?

**Thank you!**
*// sorry for the english mistakes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the code below and let me know if this works

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
         array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => $_GET["keyword"]),
         array('attribute' => 'att_wine_alias', 'like' => $_GET["keyword"])
    )
);
```

However, addFieldToFilter is also an option which works this way as below:

```
->addFieldToFilter(
    array('name', 'att_wine_alias'),
    array(
        array('like'=>'%' . $GET['keyword'] . '%'), 
        array('like'=>'%' . $GET['keyword'] . '%')
    )
 )
```

The errors mentioned in the comments below could be because of ReIndexing. Are you using Flat tables?

Just in case, if you are then you might want to REINDEX and then try once again.

Also, this could be because the way the code must have been placed in the file. Will help debug it if you can share the function where you are trying to write this code.

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding...

Comment: Okay, the first one (without the % marks) returns nothing. The second one returns mysql error: "**Unknown column 'e.n' in 'where clause'**" (I reindexed everything). I dont have any idea of our tables (flat or not), but we going to create a _custom view_ with standard SQL queries. Thank you again, and Happy Coding to you too.